# Gaussian blur image histogram of Y channel

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, matplotlib, computer-vision

I'm new to computer vision and image processing, anyway I'm trying to calculate the histogram of  image y_channel which has previously been blurred with cv2.GaussianBlur and converted from BGR to YCr-cb color space. However the end result isn't quite what I was expecting, it doesn't seems to have the typical look of a Gaussian distribution. The following is my image and plot.

[image: face image]

[image: histogram]

And this is the code snippet.

```
    cv2.imwrite("/home/carlo/face.png", roi2)    
    img = cv2.imread('/home/carlo/face.png')
    yuma = cv2.split(img)[0]
    Hist = yuma.flatten().tolist()
    grayscales  = np.unique(Hist)
    frequencies = [Hist.count(x) for x in grayscales]
    plt.figure()
    plt.bar(grayscales,frequencies,color='g',edgecolor='k')
    plt.show()
```

Can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Why do you expect the histogram to be Gaussian?  It will be a somewhat smeared version of the original distribution, but not necessarily Gaussian.  Compare what you got to the original distribution of the image.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I edited the question, I guess the face luminance should look like a Gaussian histogram.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser perhaps it might helpfull to know that I'm following this paper http://www2.tku.edu.tw/~tkjse/15-2/10-IE9920.pdf, section 3.2

Comment: it looks like your image is too bright and you have saturated the luminace channel

Comment: @tcaswell yes you're right I tried in different light conditions and I've got a positive result(by positive I mean a Gaussian look alike histogram). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It actually was a issue that occurs with to bright illumination as @tcaswell suggested to me. Under different conditions the Y histogram looks a lot like a Gaussian one.